# adding and deleting (specific) form elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamic-forms

i have a textarea and beside it are two buttons: "add another textarea" and "delete this textarea"

here is my html code:

```
<div id="summaryIn">
                            <label for="">Summary of Experience:</label> 
                            <textarea class="TA1" name="mySummary[]" value=""></textarea>
                            <button class="adddel" name="cmdDelSummary[]" id="cmdDelSummary" title="Delete this Summary" onClick="DelSummary('summaryIn');">-</button> 
                            <button class="adddel" id="cmdAddSummary" title="Add Another Summary" onClick="AddSummary('summaryIn');">+</button>
                        </div>
```

my javascript function for adding the textarea works fine, however the delete button doesn't work well, here is the javascript code:

```
function DelSummary(divName){
alert(summary_counter);
if (summary_counter == 1)
{
    document.getElementById('cmdDelSummary').disabled=true;
}
else
{
    summaryIn.removeChild(summaryIn.lastChild);
    summary_counter--;
    //alert(summary_counter);
}
```

}

i've been trying to figure this out for quite a long time now, but until now i haven't found any solution. . .i don't know how to index/reference the additional delete buttons so that the removeChild would delete that particular textarea only and not always the lastChild..thanks very much in advance :)

Comment: Where is `summaryIn` defined?

Comment: Is it alerting the right summary_counter? Also can you add the code for AddSummary

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add

```
summaryIn = document.getElementById(divName);
```

before

```
summaryIn.removeChild(summaryIn.lastChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
summaryIn.removeChild(summaryIn.lastChild);
```

seems to be dependant on the practice of making element names and ids into global variables that reference the element. That is a non-standard practice that has not been implemented by all browsers.

Instead use the standards-compliant:

```
var  summaryIn = document.getElementById('summaryIn');
```

Now you can call its *removeChild* method. You should probaby do some checking of what you are about to remove too, since initially the "Add Another Summary" button is the last element child.

#### Edit

By convention, function names starting with a capital letter are reserved for cosntructors, so I've used lower case.

To remove the div and its content from the document:

```
// Go up DOM until reach parent element with tagName
// If no such node found, return undefined.
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();

  while (el.parentNode) {
    el = el.parentNode;

    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  }
}

function delSummary(el){
  var div = upTo(el, 'div');
  div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
  <button ... onclick="delSummary(this);" ...>-</button>
```

While HTML attribute names are not case sensitive, I find that using camel case makes them hard to read and so use lower case.

Comment: thanks for the answer...however i have another question... whenever i click the "Add another Summary" it adds another <div> with the same content (with the two buttons) below the previous div.. how do i make (for example i already have 5 divs of the same content) a particular "Delete this Summary" button (let's say the second) remove that entire second div?

Comment: Presumably you are cloning the div and it's content. When the button is clicked, it can pass a reference to itself to the listener using `this` or you can use the associated event object. Then go up the *parentNode* chain to the div, then delete the entire div using `div.parentNode.removeChild(div)`.  I'll update my answer shortly.